# IE7 navbar margin and padding way off

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#"></li>
       <li><a href="#"></li>
       <li><a href="#"></li>
       <li><a href="#"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

#nav {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-left: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 230px;
 width: 800px;
}

#nav a{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li {
 display: inline;
 margin: -4px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px; 
 padding-top: 19px;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#nav li a {
 background-color: transparent;

}
```

the code above works fine in firefox with the highlighting filling out the entire "tab" of the navbar. however in ie7 it is off center and not filling up the same way. any ideas ?

Comment: Tbh i dont know how smart it is to use margin with position:absolute O.o Can you give me some demo page to see what effect are you after so i can maybe try to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close your a-tag.

And you should be careful when using padding on inline elements:

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/